# Voltage barrier of pn junction under bias

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The potential barrier of the depletion region of a zero biased diode is given by:

$$V_b=\frac {kT}{q} ln \left(\frac{N_N N_P}{n_i^2} \right)$$

However this formula doesn't tell us what happens to the voltage when we bias the diode : The voltage will become lower in  forward bias and higher in  reverse bias.

What factor am I missing ?

Comment: The factor is that you are applying an external bias to either add to or reduce the built in potential.

Comment: @JonCuster it isnt that simple because for forward voltages above this built in potential the depletion region disappears.

Comment: No, you have merely provided a forward bias larger than the built in voltage. If add enough water behind a dam it eventually comes over the top.

Comment: So you are saying that the depletion region doesnt become smaller in forward voltages.